# How can I add and remove notification observers when a UIViewController is pushed/pulled by a navigation controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I usually add the `UINotification` observer in the init method and I remove them in dealloc.

However if I have a chain of `UIViewControllers` pushed by a `UINavigationController`, they are not deallocated when the next `UIViewController` is pushed. Consequently they all observe for the notification, and this is not what I want.

How can I add and remove notification observers when a `UIViewController` is pushed/pulled by a navigation controller ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to get notified, you can set the delegate of the UINavigationController. This is quite cumbersome though, since the navigation controller only has one delegate. So in this case, I would have used `viewDidAppear:animated`, `viewDidDisappear:animated` and so on. These methods will be called on your view controllers as the navigation controller hides and shows them, and will also be called if you present a modal view controller in which case you probably also want to unregister notifications.

Comment: No, that's the point, I don't want to unregister them when a modal view controller is called. So i can't sue viewDidDisappear.

Comment: Use the UINavigationController delegate then.

Comment: How should I use it ? I mean, when a notification is triggered I need to invoke specific methods in my UIViewControllers

Answer (score 3):

Adding a second answer with an example on how to achieve this with a UINavigationControllerDelegate.

Somewhere, set the delegate to the root view controller. Either with code or by connecting it in a nib. Make your root view controller a `UINavigationControllerDelegate`.

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate>
    // ...
@end
```

Do this in the implementation of the root view controller

```
@implementation MyViewController
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController 
      willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
                    animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [viewController
        performSelector:@selector(willBeShownViaNavigationController)];

    [navigationController.visibleViewController 
        performSelector:@selector(willBeHiddenViaNavigationController)];
}
@end
```

Make sure *all* the view controllers being used in that navigation controller implements those two methods.

Note: this code is untested, there may be some errors. But you should get the idea.

Comment: Is visibleViewController working also for modalViews presented by the current visible viewController ? I'm afraid it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: The visibleViewController is the view controller that is to be presented after a navigation controller push or pop. The delegate method for the UINavigationControllerDelegate will not be called when you present modal view controllers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to subclass UINavigationController to keep track of whether it is pushing or popping.  Then in your viewWillAppear you can check to see if you're being pushed or popped.  I have a subclass for that [Here](https://github.com/progrmr/SDK_Utilities/blob/master/GM_Subclasses/GMNavController.m)